# OFFSET doesn't work when a column is sorted with all NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand why the `OFFSET` clause doesn't work when I'm retrieving a table sorted by a column that contains all `NULL` values?

For example, let's say I have a table `People` with `ID`, `Gender`, and `Race` columns. The `Race` column contains all `NULL` values.

When I run these to queries, why do they retrieve the same data?

```
SELECT * 
FROM People
ORDER BY Race ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS --offset 0 rows
    FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY

SELECT * 
FROM People
ORDER BY Race ASC
    OFFSET 15 ROWS --offset 15 rows
    FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```

I understand ordering is not functioning, since all values in `Race` column are `NULL`. I don't understand why it doesn't offset 15 rows in the second query. `OFFSET` functions properly only if the column contains some non-NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Race is not unique then the order in that group is not guaranteed to repeat. Add ID to the sort to get a repeatable sort.

```
SELECT * 
FROM People
ORDER BY Race, ID
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 15 
ROWS ONLY

SELECT * 
FROM People
ORDER BY Race, ID
OFFSET 15 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 15 
ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. What if the columns were selected from a view with no unique column?

Comment: @Lukas if there's no column to help define order, how do you guarantee order when selecting from the view *without* `offset`? Same answer: you can't, because the behavior is undefined and nondeterministic. If you want to use a column you can use to order, you'll have to expose it in the view.

Comment: Thank you. If I'm grasping this correctly, since the values are all identical and therefore can't be sorted, there's no reference point for `OFFSET` to retrieve the "next" 15 rows? If so, when I make every value in `Race` column the same (let's say the letter `X`), the offset works as expected. Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM People
ORDER BY Race ASC, row_number() over(order by Race)
--    OFFSET 0 ROWS --offset 0 rows
--    FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
    OFFSET 15 ROWS --offset 15 rows
    FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work well. Would you mind explaining what is happening here? I can tell it's creating a row number and sorting on it after Race, but I can't figure out how the `OVER` clause is working.